# Asp.net MVC- Unable to bind values to Multiselect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, bootstrap-multiselect

U have following line in my view but unable to set selected values.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>Model.Profile.PreferedLocations, new MultiSelectList(Model.Locations, "Key", "Value", Model.Profile.PreferedLocations), new { @class = "selectpicker form-control", multiple = "multiple", @data_max_options = "3" })
```

In the code above, I can see correct values for locations available and already set PreferedLocations. Please see the screenshot below:

[Screenshot of quick watch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkqY9.png)

[image]

Comment: And as a side note, you do not need the 4th parameter in the `SelectList` constructor

Comment: The suggested link solved the issue....many thanks.